# WordPress and MySQL on RDS very slow

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, rds

I have a medium website made in Wordpress with about 2.000 daily hits and 3.000 published posts. The website run on EC2 instance m3.xlarge without any problems for over one year. But I constantly had problems with RDS MySQL.

My RDS instance is as follows:

```
Engine: MySQL 5.7.11
Instance: db.m3.medium
Type: Standard - Current
Generation vCPU: 1
vCPU Memory: 3.75 GiB
EBS Optimized: no
Network Performance: Moderate
Storage Type: General Purpose (SSD)
IOPS: disabled
Storage: 100 GB SSD
Parameter groups: default
Option groups: With Memcached
Memcached configuration (default, I have no idea how to use these settings):

INNODB_API_BK_COMMIT_INTERVAL: 5
ERROR_ON_MEMORY_EXHAUSTED: 0
MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_CONNECTIONS: 1024
CHUNK_SIZE_GROWTH_FACTOR: 1.25
VERBOSITY: v
INNODB_API_DISABLE_ROWLOCK: 0
BINDING_PROTOCOL: auto
CHUNK_SIZE: 48
INNODB_API_TRX_LEVEL: 0
CAS_DISABLED: 0
DAEMON_MEMCACHED_W_BATCH_SIZE: 1
DAEMON_MEMCACHED_R_BATCH_SIZE: 1
INNODB_API_ENABLE_MDL: 0
BACKLOG_QUEUE_LIMIT: 1024
```

**The problems are:**

1) CPU RDS instance by 100% for several minutes making very slow navigation when threads connected reach 20-40 users;

2) Number of connections simultaneous has a limit of 296, but sometimes jumps from an average of 5 connections to 39 connections for several minutes 1 or 2 times a day, and drops the website.

Through Mysql Workbench I identified the problem of slow browsing and website down happens when the following SELECT runs:

```
SELECT meta_key FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_key !='_wp_page_template' AND meta_key !='_edit_last' 
    AND meta_key !='_edit_lock' AND meta_key !='_encloseme'
    AND meta_key !='_pingme' GROUP BY meta_key
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that query?  Maybe we can figure out a workaround based on the intent of the query.